# Spring Security 3.1.4 Multiple login forms on different pages, with the same Authenication Manager

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-social

I actually been stuck with this for a while now and don't now how to get further.
I want to have multiple  tags but as I understand it that's not possible in the same http block.
The reason for this is that I want the authentication-failure-url's to point to the page the login attempt comes from (and also redirect the user back to that site on successful attempt).

I have a file header.jsp where i have my login form. And I want to include this on all my pages in the future to enable the users to login from all pages without being redirected.

How do I do this?

Much of my code are taken from the spring samples. (security + social + registration example)
This is the important part of my security.xml (without any attempt of achieving this)

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http pattern="/project/" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true">

        <!-- Authentication policy -->

        <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=bad_credentials" />

        <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/addcourse" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <!--<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />-->

</http>
```

As I understand it I could use multiple HTTP blocks? Something like this:

```
<!-- Login place 1, sign in page -->
<http pattern="/signin" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?error=bad_credentials" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/addcourse" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<!--Login place 2, start page -->
<http pattern="/" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/?error=bad_credentials" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

This gives me

```
Sep 26, 2013 11:57:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'providerSignInController' defined in class path resource [com/courseportal/project/config/SocialConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#1

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
```

Another attempt is to make a filter in security.xml that routes the traffic right. Im not sure about how to do this.

I hope someone can help me with this, and say what approach is the appropriate one.

Best regards,
Nilsi

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer exactly on

> The reason for this is that I want the authentication-failure-url's to point to the page the login attempt comes from (and also redirect the user back to that site on successful attempt).

To do so on our project we add very simple entry point as follow:

```
<http ... entry-point-ref="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
   ...
```

After that in the same spring we defining entry point:

```
<bean id="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
 class="YOU_CLASS_LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
 <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/signin" />
</bean>
```

Now you have declare entry-point as extension of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`. The purpose of this to add to login url returning path to real page after sign-in, so your login url will look like a: `http://mysite/signin?redirect_url=http://mysite/some_page.jsp`

```
import import org.springframework.security.web.util.*;
...
public class YOU_CLASS_LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint extends
    LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {
...
@Override
protected String buildRedirectUrlToLoginPage(
      HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException authException) {
//following code check if your on login page already, then you don't add redirect
    String loginForm = 
        determineUrlToUseForThisRequest(request, response, authException);

    if (UrlUtils.isAbsoluteUrl(loginForm)) {
        return loginForm;
    }
```

After that using `RedirectUrlBuilder` create the path that looks like `http://mysite/signin?redirect_url=http://mysite/some_page.jsp` and return it from this method. Almost done....

After success login analyze parameter `redirect_url` and redirect user to it page

Answer (score -1):

POST the login form via Ajax, and if necessary, refresh the current page upon successful login (possibly prompting the user to do it) or display an error message "Login failed" upon failed login.

To do this, implement a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `AuthenticationFailureHandler`:

Success: return HTTP 204 No Content as an indication of success and reload page at client-side

Failure: return HTTP 401 Unauthorized to indicate failure, and display error message at client-side